# Rails - different form tabs, different controllers

Tags: controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Bootstrap 4 form with different tabs. To unify user experience, I want to show everything in one place - management of: users, pictures, comments (3 tabs total). As every tab is processed by a different controller, I wonder what the best approach to such problem is.

I would like to process every entity in its controller, but return to that form again and to further processing from there, e.g. add a picture to a gallery in the Pictures tab.

Mixing this in one big controller is an utter nonsense, so how do you go about this? Using AJAX?

Comment: I guess with AJAX you can visually have single view with those tabs, but behind the scenes there are different controllers, routes with appropriate data. Seems that [this could be your case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532483/how-do-i-fetch-the-content-for-each-tab-using-ajax-rails4-bootstrap3).

Comment: As @matiss says, views, routes and controllers can be a whole different story. You can have different forms pointing each to a different controller, each form in a different tab. And the route can be the root, and different routes per form.